# Roll Up SQL Query?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, tfs, subquery

It's been ages since I've worked in SQL, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I'm working with a TFS database, and I'm trying to do a query report against it to get the sum of all the "OriginalEstimate" field, for items in the current sprint iteration and forward.

i.e., if the data was laid out like this:

```
Sprint Name | Original Estimate Total       
Sprint #1:  | 10
Sprint #2:  | 20
Sprint #3:  | 30
Sprint #4:  | 40
```

I'd like to get a data set returned that looks like this:

```
Sprint Name | Original Estimate Total       
Sprint #1:  | 90
Sprint #2:  | 70
Sprint #3:  | 40
Sprint #4:  | 0
```

First off, I don't even know if the above is possible using SQL.  Let me know if not. :)

Where things get hairier to start with, is me understanding how to do this in TFS SQL server table structure.  I can't modify the structure, so any idea on how to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

If you're unfamiliar with TFS's database layout, here's a quick table summary, snipped down and renamed a bit to make it easier to grok:

```
(Table) Iteration
-----------------
IterationName
IterationGuid

(Table) WorkItem
----------------
ID
Name
IterationGUID      // Relates to Iteration table, above
StartDate
OriginalEstimate   // The field I care about, only valid on 'Task' in our case.
WorkItemType       // Used to distinguish the type, for our purposes assume only 'Task' and 'Sprint' exist
```

Quick description:

"WorkItem"'s in TFS are everything from backlogs, tasks, to 'sprints'.  A 'sprint' is simply an entry that contains a StartDate and an EndDate for accounting your sprint start/ends, and also links to the Iteration that all the tasks will as well.

So, what I want is the data mentioned above, grouped by the Sprint's "Name", ordered by the Sprint's "StartDate", that is the forward-sum of all sprints ahead of it.

And this is where I want to blow my brains out.

If this is possible and I simply need to do more reading, please let me know what to look up.  I can't seem to make this fly with subqueries, but perhaps I'm simply not using them right.

Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about TFS, but could this be solved with plain SQL from SQL Server or you require something else? Besides, can you provide sample data for the actual tables? I don't know how to relate the first two sets of data to the actual tables :(

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answers you've received? 10 days and no reaction whatsoever isn't very nice.

Comment: I apologize on the delay, Tomalak, but this report has taken a lower priority in my life at this point, and I haven't had time to try any of the solutions.  Please forgive any breach in etiquette that I wasn't aware of.  I'll report back when I get the time to give it a try.

Comment: @Eddie No need for a formal apology. I'm just saying that *some* kind of feedback would have been good. This browser tab ob mine is open since March 2. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, these answers all helped me steer towards what I needed to do, but none was complete enough on it's own.  Here's the final solution I found:

```
SELECT        Name, Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate AS StartDate,
                         (SELECT        SUM(Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate) AS OriginalEstimateTotal
                           FROM            CurrentWorkItemView AS wi1
                           WHERE        (IterationPath IN
                                                         (SELECT        IterationPath
                                                           FROM            CurrentWorkItemView AS wi2
                                                           WHERE        (WorkItemType = 'Sprint') AND 
                                                                                     (Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate > wi3.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate))) AND (State NOT IN ('Removed'))) 
                     AS OriginalEstimateTotal
FROM            CurrentWorkItemView AS wi3
WHERE        (WorkItemType = 'Sprint') AND (State <> 'Removed')
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Ideally I'd like to move this query to a MDX query, but I haven't the foggiest.  If anyone has any input on that, that'd be great. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best performance, but one way to get results like what you show is to use a scalar subquery in the select statement. Your sample and result data seem to differ from your explanation. So, I just went by your sample data, i.e., I summed the value for all tasks greater than the current one.

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT SUM(originalestimate) AS oe
        FROM   workitem AS wi1
        WHERE  wi1.id = wi2.id
               AND wi1.startdate > wi2.startdate) AS oe_total
FROM   workitem AS wi2
WHERE  workitemtype = 'Task'
ORDER  BY name,
          startdate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  wi.id, wi.name,
  SUM(ahead.originalestimate) ahead_estimate
FROM
  workitem wi
  INNER JOIN workitem ahead ON ahead.id = wi.id 
                               AND ahead.startdate > wi.startdate
WHERE
  workitemtype = 'Task'
GROUP BY
  wi.id, wi.name
ORDER BY
  wi.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily in SSRS - simply create a column for your Roll up value, then enter a formula like the following into the expression for the detail row cell in the roll up column:

```
=Sum(Fields!OriginalEstimate.Value, "DataSet1")-Fields!OriginalEstimate.Value
```

Comment: This doesn't yield the results I want, sadly.  It gives me the total sum of OriginalEstimate across all sprints, minus the current one.  When what I want is the sume of originalestimate across all sprints, minus the sum of all previous ones *including* this one.  Is there a simple way of accomplishing that with SSRS?  I'd love to learn more.